# Can we remove the [selenium] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I regularly watch the [selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium) and [selenium-webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver) tags and find that they are (generally) used interchangeably ([selenium] for [selenium-webdriver]). Occasionally IDE or RC gets mixed in there too which makes watching [selenium] a mixed bag and many times a duplication of [selenium-webdriver].

The description of [selenium] states, "When using this tag, also include other tags for the specific components you are using, e.g. selenium-webdriver for the language bindings, selenium-ide, selenium-grid, etc." So why even have [selenium]? If it is removed, users will be forced to be specific on what Selenium flavor they are referring to. If they search for selenium tags, all the relevant (more specific) tags are easily found.

So... can we please remove [selenium]?

Comment: The reason [tag:selenium] exists is so that people can follow the tag, if they want to watch all selenium-related questions, rather than limiting themselves to just [tag:selenium-webdriver] or just [tag:selenium-ide], or having to watch all of them. That's the reason for that statement in the description.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan are you saying that all the subtags, e.g. [selenium-webdriver], etc. all roll up into [selenium]? Because that's not the case. You can look at newest on both those tags and exclude the questions that have both tags and prove that to yourself.

Comment: Is [tag:webdriver] actually [tag:selenium-webdriver]?

Comment: @Deduplicator when I read the [webdriver description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/webdriver/info), my understanding is that selenium-webdriver is a single, specific implementation of webdriver. From looking at the first 20 or so questions in the webdriver tag, my guess is that 90% of the webdriver traffic is selenium-webdriver. Maybe I should open another question and see if we can get [webdriver] removed also since there are specific tags addressing the individual implementations of it (or they could be added).

Comment: @Deduplicator: WebDriver started out as an original Selenium project. Since then, it's been standardized as a W3C spec in https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver, making Selenium WebDriver one implementation of the WebDriver spec. As of now I don't believe there are any other implementations of the spec, but I suspect the generic tag is still worth keeping around as a "standards-based WebDriver" sort of tag.

Comment: @BoltClock I don't disagree that [webdriver] is a thing and should be its own tag but it's highly misused as a (not-so) interchangeable replacement for [selenium-webdriver]. [selenium] on the other hand really is of no use. If I were to use the [selenium] tag, I would need to then use three tags... [selenium][selenium-webdriver] and [c#] (or whatever language I'm using). To me this just makes [selenium] too redundant. The last two are clear enough to indicate what my topic my question covers.

Answer (score -2):

You saw it right. The description of [selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selenium/info) tag clearly states *when using this tag, also include other tags for the specific components you are using, e.g. selenium-webdriver for the language bindings, selenium-ide, selenium-grid, etc* as [**Selenium**](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium) is the umbrella project which comprises multiple software tools where each tool has a specific role. In short *Selenium* is a *Browser Automation Framework and a Ecosystem*.

About [*selenium-webdriver*](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selenium-webdriver/info) :

- [**Selenium-WebDriver**](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp) is developed to support dynamic web pages in a better way through a well-designed object-oriented API that provides improved support for modern advanced web-app testing requirements.

Fundamentally there are a lot of differences between *Selenium* and *WebDriver*. This screenshot which I often refer to the global audience will surely address your question in the best possible way.

[image: SeleniumVSwebdriver]

So questions related to specific tools/project which falls under the umbrella project *Selenium* must contain the specific project tag e.g. *selenium-webdriver*, *Selenium IDE*, *Selenium Grid*, *protractor*, *webdriverio*, *webdrivermanager* and can also additionally include the *selenium* tag for a better representation of the question.

Comment: This question is about the redundancy of [selenium] when the other Selenium related tags already exist, e.g. [selenium-webdriver], etc. Your answer doesn't address this. If I add [selenium][selenium-webdriver][c#] to my question... what extra information is gained by having the [selenium] tag there?

Comment: You've also confused [webdriver] with the other tags discussed. Your slide is talking about [webdriver] and [selenium-webdriver] (mislabeled as Selenium in your slide) which further adds to the general confusion around these tags and this discussion.